# How do I set up a reverse proxy on the same physical server as a hosted website using apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

How can I use one server to do the following two tasks:

1. Serve a website hosted at http://foo.bar.com
2. Direct all traffic intended for http://loremipsum.bar.com to "http ://www. acme.com:87 60/Application" using a reverse proxy.

The website is already present and configured properly, I just need to add the functionality of #2. How can I do this on the same physical server? I imagine the answer is to use Virtualhosts, but I don't know how to do both on one physical box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a new VirutalHost section for `loremipsum.bar.com`.

It would look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / http://www.acme.com:8760/Application
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.acme.com:8760/Application
  ServerName loremipsum.bar.com
 </VirtualHost>
```